# pythonについて。配列の中に負数が含まれているかどうかを判別したい。

Tags: python

タイトルにある通りです。ある配列が用意してあり、その中に負数が含まれている場合、`True`を、
含まれていない場合、`False`を出力させたいです。
例えば

```
array = [-1, 0, 5]
```

では`True`

```
array = [2, 4, 4]
```

では`False`
となります。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[any()](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/functions.html#any)を使えば良いと思います。

> iterable のいずれかの要素が真ならば True を返します。iterable が空なら False を返します。

以下のようになるでしょう。

```
result = any((x < 0 for x in array))
```

---

参考：(以下は正の時をTrueにしていますが)
[Pythonのall関数を用いてリストの要素がすべて空文字列か判定する](https://techblog.recochoku.jp/5344)

> 開発中にPythonで「リストの要素がすべて空文字列か」という判定をしたい場面があり、なにかないかと調べてみたら、allという組み込み関数で簡単に実装できました。
>   今回はそのall、対になるanyを紹介します。
>
> これを使えば、「リストの要素がすべて正の数か」の判定が以下のように書けたり
>
> ```
> all((x >= 0 for x in [1, 2, 3])) # => True
> all((x >= 0 for x in [1, 2, -3])) # => False
> ```
>
> anyを使って、「リストの要素が一つでも正の数か」の判定が以下のように書けます。
>
> ```
> any((x >= 0 for x in [1, -2, -3])) # => True
> any((x >= 0 for x in [-1, -2, -3])) # => False
> ```

Answer (score 2):

「負数が含まれている」＝「最小値が0未満」と読み替えて

```
min(array) < 0
```

で良いかと.